# Running Junit5, Serenity and Cucumber from main class does not generate a report

Tags: cucumber, report, junit5, serenity-bdd

I have a test project that runs e2e tests and until now I built a .jar file, upload it to a test environment and then executed the tests against a test environment. The tests run serenity with cucumber. I would like to migrate the project now to junit5. The tests are started in a main method like this:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
    SummaryGeneratingListener summaryGeneratingListener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();
    LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
            .selectors(selectClass(AllTests.class))
            .build();
    launcher.execute(
            request,
            summaryGeneratingListener);

    boolean wasSuccessful = summaryGeneratingListener.getSummary().getFailures().isEmpty();
    
    HtmlAggregateStoryReporter reporter = new HtmlAggregateStoryReporter("default");
    File reportTarget = new File("target");
    reporter.setOutputDirectory(reportTarget);
    reporter.setGenerateTestOutcomeReports();
    reporter.generateReportsForTestResultsFrom(reportTarget);

    if (!wasSuccessful) {
      System.exit(1);
    } else {
      if (isAutomaticRetryThresholdBreached()) {
        System.exit(1);
      }
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
```

This code executes the tests but does not generate a HTML report with serenity.

I managed to generate serenity reports with maven-surefire-plugin, but I would like to run tests as a jar.
Do you know how to edit this code so that it generates a report?

Comment: The `HtmlAggregateStoryReporter` isn't connected to the test execution in anyway. I do not see how this could possibly work. You should probably check the documentation for Serenity.

Comment: With Junit4, a similar code was running. The `HtmlAggregateStoryReporter` was also not connected, but I think it used the generated report in the ./target directory to generate the HTML report. What I am trying to do here is simply to run serenity with cucumber and junit5 from a main method, not from maven or gradle.

Comment: something like this was what I was looking for: https://github.com/petrac-daniel/serenity-cucumber-junit5-demo
I still have one issue with it: how to run only a subset of tests here:
Previously we could run it with CUCUMBER_FILTER_TAGS environment variable. This now doesn't work anymore.

Comment: That should still work, if it doesn't and you can make a reproducer without Serenity and only Cucumber, you can create bug report with Cucumber on GitHub.

Comment: You can also put a breakpoint here and debug yourself https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/737f49d46cff10ca911a18c32ce9bece99437be1/cucumber-junit-platform-engine/src/main/java/io/cucumber/junit/platform/engine/NodeDescriptor.java#L141

Comment: I actually managed to solve the issue, but I ended up completely using the main method that is in serenity-cucumber package.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with using the main method from serenity-cucumber.jar file. Here the example:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    RuntimeOptions propertiesFileOptions = (new CucumberPropertiesParser()).parse(CucumberProperties.fromPropertiesFile()).build();
    RuntimeOptions environmentOptions = (new CucumberPropertiesParser()).parse(CucumberProperties.fromEnvironment()).build(propertiesFileOptions);
    RuntimeOptions systemOptions = (new CucumberPropertiesParser()).parse(CucumberProperties.fromSystemProperties()).build(environmentOptions);
    CommandlineOptionsParser commandlineOptionsParser = new CommandlineOptionsParser(System.out);
    RuntimeOptions runtimeOptions = commandlineOptionsParser.parse(args).addDefaultGlueIfAbsent().addDefaultFeaturePathIfAbsent().addDefaultSummaryPrinterIfNotDisabled().enablePublishPlugin().build(systemOptions);

    Runtime runtime = CucumberWithSerenityRuntime.using(Main.class::getClassLoader, runtimeOptions);

    try {
        runtime.run();
    } finally {
        // byte exitStatus = net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main.run(args, ClassLoaders::getDefaultClassLoader);
        HtmlAggregateStoryReporter reporter = new HtmlAggregateStoryReporter("default");
        File reportOutput = new File("target");
        File reportInput = new File("target");
        if (!reportOutput.exists()) {
            Files.createDirectory(reportOutput.toPath());
        }
        reporter.setOutputDirectory(reportOutput);
        reporter.setGenerateTestOutcomeReports();
        reporter.generateReportsForTestResultsFrom(reportInput);

        System.exit(runtime.exitStatus());
    }
}
```

}